# Use of unresolved identifier 'connections'; did you mean 'Connections' in Auth0?

Tags: ios, swift, auth0, auth0-lock

I'm working on Auth0 Lock integration, i'm getting error **Use of unresolved identifier 'connections'; did you mean 'Connections'?.**

```
.withConnections {_ in
  connections.database(name: "Username-Password-Authentication", requiresUsername: true)
}
```

I changed code to

```
Connections.database(name: "Username-Password-Authentication", requiresUsername: true)
```

Now I'm getting error **Instance member 'database' cannot be used on type 'Connections'**

When I changed code to

```
Connections().database(name: "Username-Password-Authentication", requiresUsername: true)
```

Getting error **'Connections' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers**

I changed code to

```
$0.database(name: "Username-Password-Authentication", requiresUsername: true)
```

Getting **Anonymous closure arguments cannot be used inside a closure that has explicit arguments**

https://github.com/auth0/Lock.swift

https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock-ios/v2#configuration-options

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    Lock
        .classic()
        // withConnections, withOptions, withStyle, and so on
        .withOptions {
            $0.oidcConformant = true
            $0.scope = "openid profile"
        }
        .onAuth { credentials in
            // Let's save our credentials.accessToken value
        }
        .withConnections {_ in
            connections.database(name: "Username-Password-Authentication", requiresUsername: true)
        }
        .withStyle {
            $0.title = "Company LLC"
            $0.logo = LazyImage(name: "123.png")
            $0.primaryColor = UIColor(red: 0.6784, green: 0.5412, blue: 0.7333, alpha: 1.0)
        }
        .present(from: self)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the Auth0 documentation is erroneous here. If you look at the [Lock.swift source file](https://github.com/auth0/Lock.swift/blob/master/Lock/Lock.swift#L142) you see that a `ConnectionBuildable` is passed as argument. You need to use this to build your connections.

Try this:

```
.withConnections { connections in
    connections.database(name: "Username-Password-Authentication", requiresUsername: true)
}
```

or the same thing using anonymous closure arguments:

```
.withConnections {
    $0.database(name: "Username-Password-Authentication", requiresUsername: true)
}
```

Comment: It seems in this case the documentation from Auth0 is erroneous. If you want to learn more about closures, check out the Swift docs: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html

Comment: have you any idea about Auth0 lock implementation in Swift.

Comment: I have never used this framework in Swift, if that’s what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

The *error* is in the **closure** for .withConnections
You are not naming a parameter by using **_**

Without parameter

`.withConnections { _ in }`

With a parameter

`.withConnections { connections in {
 connections.database(name: "Username-Password-Authentication", requiresUsername: true)
}`

Comment: For sure, search in google hackingwithswift closures. The first link has a good overview. Sean Allen in youtube has another good explanation. And if you want to get in depth check Advance Swift from Paul Hudson.

Answer (score 1):

You get **Use of unresolved identifier 'connections'; did you mean 'Connections'?** because `connections` is not declared as closure parameters.

Try:

```swift
.withConnections { connections in
  connections.database(name: "Username-Password-Authentication", requiresUsername: true)
}
```

or if you want using anonymous argument, do not declare any parameter:

```swift
.withConnections { 
  $0.database(name: "Username-Password-Authentication", requiresUsername: true)
}
```